# Add Guice to POM causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap

Tags: selenium-webdriver, guice, nosuchmethoderror

I try to use Guice to Dependency Injction but when I add dependency to POM compiler returs

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap

I found threads with this bug but they described problem with Guava which I don't use in my project.
I don't even call the Guice in my tests - adding to POM and compile is enough to get this bug. I don't use DriverManager as separated dependency - it's implemented into Selenium.

Full trace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'

    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:71)
    at ui.BaseTest.testSetUp(BaseTest.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:823)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:590)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:221)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:969)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:829)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:431)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:391)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)


Test ignored.
```

POM

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.24.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

BaseTest

```
package ui;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


public abstract class BaseTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected WebDriverWait wait;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void testSetUp() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(7));
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void closeDriver(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        if (ITestResult.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) {
            String path = takeScreenshot(result);
            System.out.println("Test screenshot is available at: " + path);
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

    private String takeScreenshot(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        LocalDateTime timeNow = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss");

        File screenshotsDirectory = new File("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\screenshots\\");
        if (!screenshotsDirectory.exists()) {
            screenshotsDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        String path = screenshotsDirectory + "\\" + result.getName() + " " + formatter.format(timeNow) + ".png";
        FileHandler.copy(screenshot, new File(path));
        return path;
    }
}
```

I tried to downgrade Selenium version to 4.7.1 and yesterday it worked, today it doesn't.